# Custom SQL query ORDER BY term_order

Tags: sql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have custom taxonomy that list terms under "series" that contain posts that are also present in terms under "media_type" and where media_type is term_id 16.

I want to order the list by the term_order column in the terms table but it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$q_result = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->terms}.name 
    FROM {$wpdb->terms}
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} 
            ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} 
            ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'series' 
        AND {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id IN (
            SELECT object_id 
            FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships}
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} 
                    ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'media_type' 
                AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = '16'
            ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order 
        );"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your order by is nested inside the select IN (...) clause. Try moving the closing paren up a line and leave the term_order part on the outer clause:

```
    AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = '16')
ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order;"
```

As it is, you're ordering the results of the IN clause which isn't changing the order that the items are actually returned to you.

NOTE: My original post mistakenly said "Move the closing parenthesis and semicolon up a line". You just need to move the parenthesis. If you move the semicolon you terminate the SQL early. Sorry for that!

Comment: I made ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order go after the first closing tag ); but it showed an empty array

Comment: Can you post the query you said returns an empty array?

Comment: I'm using echo "<pre>"; print_r( $q_result ); echo "</pre>"; to see the query results. I have not tried posting.

Comment: I got it to work! I had to remove the semicolon in the first closing parenthesis. How do you post the array?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is going on. I only see one closing parenthesis and semicolon in the query you posted above, but I'm glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95615/custom-sql-query-order-by-term-order) 
In your case   you are referring `ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order` and as default in `wordpress`  `wp_terms` table don't have this column the `term_order` column resides in the `wp_term_relationships` table

Comment: I went into phpMyAdmin and the wp_terms table has a column called term_order. I'm using a plugin the assign the numbers to the terms.